# Is it OK to ask your friends to upvote your posts?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, upvotes, voting-fraud

Some users post their questions/answers and tell their friends to upvote them in order to increase their reputation. Is this okay? If not, can we prevent it somehow, like with a reputation audit?

Comment: That's a form of [sock puppeting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260407/1043380), which is not allowed. Upvote on your own terms, not because someone else told you to do so.

Comment: @gunr2171 Sock puppeting would be creating multiple accounts just to upvote yourself.  This is a type of voting fraud that is separate from sock puppeting.

Comment: ..But the term Sock puppeting is suitable here also, as the user upvote post without checking the quality and content of the post just because other user told,Dont you think the same?

Comment: If you have to ask your friends to up-vote your posts, you probably don't deserve the up-votes, as I would presume your friends would up-vote it without you asking if it were truly a good post.

Comment: What about asking programming friends who don't have accounts, to sign up, and only upvote answers they think are good, and solve a problem they have had. I have a lot of answers to questions that my friends often ask me who don't use stack overflow.

Comment: Colluding with others to either upvote or downvote answers is not permitted.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

We highly recommend that you not ask your friends to vote for your content simply because you were the one who left it. We do recognize that people will naturally tend to vote for people they know, and only step in when this becomes a bad enough problem that it is skewing votes on questions and answers. We even have a standard message that we send out about this, which I'll quote from here:

> We recently noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to
>   or from specific users. While we encourage everyone to upvote great
>   posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits
>   of the post, not the person who wrote it. This is just a reminder to
>   please refrain from targeting specific users when voting.
>
> Stack Exchange works by ensuring that the best information rises to
>   the top. Voting specifically for content that benefits your friends,
>   family or colleagues unfairly skews that system, and continuing to do
>   so can result in a lengthy suspension for all involved.
>
> The system has processes in place to detect various types of voting
>   between groups of users, so if you know anyone who may be voting for
>   your stuff in kind, please ask them to refrain before the system
>   detects such activity and takes similar actions on their account.
>
> This is often just a simple misunderstanding, so no harm done. But
>   continued activity of this sort can result in a prolonged suspension
>   for all involved, so please let me know if you have any questions
>   regarding this policy.

As you can see, we try to nudge people in the right direction first, and only take more serious action if this persists. Tim Post [has written about factors that can lead to targeted voting](https://web.archive.org/web/20150201115645/http://alertfalse.com/2013/10/lessons-from-hofstede-part-1-power-distance/), and we try to educate about this before assuming malice.

Comment: I wonder how many people help in fact each other with upvotes, but making sure they don't fall into any of these technical traps. While newbies may get banned and penalized when they have nobody to vote up their questions. Just saying, reality check...

Answer (score 18):

Is it *not* acceptable to go around upvoting all of your friends' posts, no.  Can we stop it...sometimes.  We do what we can.  Of course, sometimes the behavior isn't really distinguishable from real votes, but the mods and devs do what they can.

If you suspect a particular user is committing some form of voting fraud, flag one of their posts and explain what you believe to be happening and what reason you have to believe that it's going on and someone will look into it.

Comment: What about work mates you share your problem with, but they aren't associated to the problem fully? They care about the solution almost as much as you do, since its solution would help the company we both work for? So is an upvote justified if they look over it and want to upvote it by themselves?

Comment: @modiX No, that would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

No,

But it is OK to ask your friends to **look** at a question you have posted if you think they can answer it.

Some of them may up vote the question, others may down vote it.    I have done both when a friend has asked me to look at one of their questions.

Answer (score 6):

Developers tend to be antisocial creatures. Even if you have 100+ contacts among all the social networks you use combined, you'll probably only have a handful friends in your real life.

Stack Overflow has an amount of active users that is quite more than a handful<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. I believe in nearly all cases any upvotes that are awarded based on friendship should be more than offset by downvotes awarded due to a question being half-assed. No need to worry too much about that.

As gunr commented:

> Upvote on your own terms, not because someone else told you to do so.

Comment: This is what happening nearby that's why I asked this question...

Comment: nice ... liked it...